# Rails allow POST for Ajax on index action without breaking CREATE

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a simple setup for a resource, currently in routes.rb I have:

```
resources :leave_requests
```

This works exactly as expected, on the index view I have a datatable setup using Ajax via a GET, this is also working but the URI is getting very large during the Ajax request. I would prefer this to be a POST action, for this to work I require a POST instead of a GET on the index action in my routes.

However, this will break the CREATE action i.e. will simply load the index page on submitting a new request. i.e. If I do this:

```
post '/leave_requests', to: 'leave_requests#index'
resources :leave_requests
```

How can I get these to co-exist happily?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to do something like in this [Rails , Ajax , Post Function , Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17191517/1380867) the code looks something like

```
$('form').submit(function()
    {
     var myForm =  $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax
         ({
            url:'/leave_request/create',
             type:"POST",
             dataType:'json',
             data: myForm,
             processData:false,
            success: function (msg)
            {
            alert(msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status)
            {
            alert(xhr.error);
            }
         });
    });
```

you can also take a look at [jQuery post to Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238119/1380867)