# How to pass javascript variable into embeded ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, leaflet

I'm developing a Rails app with Leaflet. I have model **Pipe** with field **location** that is type **linestring**. I want to be able to click on the map, get the coordinates of that spot and return number of pipes that are at certain distance of it. I can't return coordinates to Ruby. I realize that Ruby gets executed before Javascript, so how do I do it? 
This is the function in my .js.erb file:

```
    function onMapClick(e) {
      var sql = <%= Pipe.where{st_dwithin((location),ST_GeomFromText("POINT(#{e.latlng.lat} #{e.latlon.lon})", 4326), 3000)}.count.to_s %>;
      map.openPopup(sql.toString(), e.latlng);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass data from JavaScript to the server you have to make an ajax call

Comment: Could you show me an example? Do I need to make it return .json somewhere?

Comment: You could maybe find some help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237720/jquery-post-to-rails

Comment: `function onMapClick(e) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/temps",
            type: "POST",
            data: {coordinates: {lat: e.latlon.lat, lon: e.latlon.lon}},
            success: function(response) {
            }
          });
    };

    map.on('click', onMapClick);`

I hate not being able to make new line here :/ Sorry. I'm trying this, but can't get it work at all.