# How to render rails partial after a successful ajax POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

**Problem:** Partial does not update after ajax post request. Create.js.erb does not execute. I have added a console.log message to this file and it never appears in the console.

After submitting the form, I look at the logs and see the post was successfully created:

```
Started POST "/runs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-11 08:57:25 -0700
  Processing by RunsController#create as JS
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "run"=>{"skater_id"=>"2", "competition_id"=>"31", "start_time"=>"1", "stop_time"=>"2", "score"=>"5", "best_trick"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Run"}
    User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
     (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "runs" ("start_time", "stop_time", "skater_id", "competition_id", "score", "best_trick", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["start_time", 1], ["stop_time", 2], ["skater_id", 2], ["competition_id", 31], ["score", 5.0], ["best_trick", "f"], ["created_at", "2017-04-11 15:57:25.602458"], ["updated_at", "2017-04-11 15:57:25.602458"]]
     (2.0ms)  commit transaction
  Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
```

**Run's Controller**

```
def create
  @run = Run.new(run_params)
  @runs = Run.all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @run.save
      format.json { render json: @runs }
      format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Run was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @run.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#run-breakdown").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'runs/run') %>");

/* let's check and see if this is executing */
console.log("Is this file being executed?..");
```

**Run Creation Form**

```
<%= form_for(@run, remote: true, :html => {class:"form-horizontal", role: "form", id:"run-creation-form"}) do |x| %>
    <!-- FIELDS & STYLING REMOVED FOR BREVITY -->
    <%= x.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Here's what I know:**

- the form is set to data-remote="true" so the form is handled by JS
- the form is submitted as POST request to the /runs route
- the runs controller is set to respond_to ajax
- the create.js.erb file *should* automatically be called since the controller is set to handle JS.

**Here's what has me slightly confused:**

- Do I need an .ajax method *if* I have a create.js.erb file? Other SO questions mention setting the dataType = "script". To the best of my knowledge, I should not need this file. For example:

  ```
  $('#run-creation-form').submit(function() {
      var valuesToSubmit = JSON.stringify($(this).serialize());
      console.log(valuesToSubmit);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../runs/',
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "script"
      }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // $('#run-breakdown').html(data);
      }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    return false; // prevents normal behaviour
    });
  };
  ```
- When I try to use the js above, the post request returns a 500 error when dataType is set to script. It works properly if I set the dataType to json, yet the partial still does not render.

**Sources I have consulted** (I don't have enough reputation to post ALL the links):

- https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#code-relationships_controller_ajax
- [jQuery post to Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237720/jquery-post-to-rails)
- Rails Guides: Working with Javascript
- Numerous other SO posts

I've spent a good amount of time on this before posting here. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'll be a happy man. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your controller up to respond to JS. Remember that `js != json`.

```
def create
  @run = Run.new(run_params)
  @runs = Run.all
  respond_to do |format|
    if @run.save
      format.json { render json: @runs }
      format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Run was successfully created.' }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @run.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Not passing a block will trigger the rails default behaviour of rendering `create.erb.js`.

> Do I need an .ajax method if I have a create.js.erb file?

No. You're using [the Rails UJS driver](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) to send an ajax request already. Otherwise the response type in the log would be `:html`.

> Other SO questions mention setting the dataType = "script". To the best of my knowledge, I should not need this file.

You're correct. Rails UJS defaults to using a javascript accept type header. Its only if you want a JSON response for example that you need to set the dataType.

Comment: On a side note - don't use `redirect_to :back` it relies on the browser sending a  [http referer header.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is missing format.js. Rails will look for it when you make an AJAX request.

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @run.save
     format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Run was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render json: @runs }
     format.js
    else
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this in your controller's create method:

```
 respond_to do |format|
    if @run.save
      format.json { render json: @runs }
      format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => 'Run was successfully created.' }
      format.js {}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @run.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
```

We need to specify a format to render. You didn't specify js format. when format.js is found empty rails checks if a file of methods name exists and render that js. `create.js.erb` in this case. You can also specify other file as:

```
format.js { render "some_other_jserb_file"}
```

Hope this helps..