# POST payload data to database using XMLHttpRequest rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, xmlhttprequest, ruby-on-rails-5, gojs

I'm working on a tournament bracket based on the [GOjs library](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/tournament.html), The bracket has score input.

Once my user is done editing the bracket I save the bracket into a JSON variable :

```
function save() {
    var tojs = myDiagram.model.toJSON();
    var payload = JSON.parse(tojs);
    stringify_tojs = JSON.stringify(payload);
    myDiagram.isModified = false;
```

I use XMLHttpRequest to able to post the payload into my rails model that handles 'payload' :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = callback;
    request.open("post", "http://localhost:3000/malesingles");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send(payload);
```

> I don't know where I went wrong but I'm certain it's around my
>   controller params but I can't find my mistake already been a week, the
>   controller looks something like this :

```
@tournoi = Tournoi.new(bracket_params)
  if @tournoi.save
    redirect_to root_url
    flash[:success] = "Your tournament bracket has been validated!"
  #  redirect_to @tournoi
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

end

I have included the bracket_params in private settings

```
def bracket_params
      params.require(:tournoi).permit(:payload)
     end
```

Tried different method to post the payload none really work, would appreciate some help to understand where I went wrong, I get a param is missing or empty :/.

Comment: try to require pry in controller at the top of the file and before you create a new instance of your model Tournoi add `binding.pry` in your controller and run your action, what's in `bracket_params` at that point ?

Comment: Maybe `JSON.parse(params)`

Comment: @DavidDacruz tournoi uses ` bracket_params params.require(:tournoi).permit(:payload)`

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio i get a  (no implicit conversion of nil into string) when i use JSON.parse(params[:payload])

Comment: @DezzH try params[:tournoi][:payload]

Comment: @guillaume_fr i still get a " undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" on my params parsing of tournoi and payload

Comment: @guillaume_fr before getting the undefined method for nil class, for my post request i get an Error while parsing request parameters followed by a Contents : [object object], i told myself maybe its because naming the script var payload same as the parameters is the reason why, changing the name i still get the same error.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio before getting the undefined method for nil class, for my post request i get an Error while parsing request parameters followed by a Contents : [object object], i told myself maybe its because naming the script var payload same as the parameters is the reason why, changing the name i still get the same error.

Comment: the error must be because you call `bracket_params` which runs `params.require(:tournoi).permit(:payload)` but your `params` do not include the `params[:tournoi]` hash. if you want to have that hash in your params probably you need to pass it with the correct format 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237720/jquery-post-to-rails?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio i dont understand what you mean by using the correct format, sorry i  dont even have a junior level in dev, the other examples uses ajax for the request i'm using xmlhttprequest to send my payload, i just want to able to submit the javascript variable as my json payload, how can include tournoi hash into params or can be able to do it without the need of having the tournoi hash can i exclude it?

Comment: @DezzH check out my latest commits from my repo https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/sprachspiel/tree/feature/purchase-system I just built something like that using coffescript.. the commits include description of my work

Answer (score 0):

@DezzH check out my latest commits from my repo https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/sprachspiel/tree/feature/purchase-system I just built something like that using coffescript.. the commits include description of my work

basically what I figured out is, `post` request do not pass the parameters in the url so it is not easy to find them in the request, but you can check in your network tab

as you can see from the image I am passing

```
 createPurchase: -> 
    $.ajax
       url: "/products"
       method: "POST"
       dataType: "json"
       data: { items: {product_id: '1', name: 'test' }}
       error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
         console.log "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"
       success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
         console.log "Successful AJAX call: #{data}"
         console.log data
```

[image]

then I set just a binding.pry in the controller and I can see my params there

[image]