# NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, xmlhttprequest, ruby-on-rails-5

Heey i'm working on a ruby app, i have parse my script into a JSON variable.`var tojs = myDiagram.model.toJSON();`, so now using XMLHttpRequest i send this variable to my model.

```
request.open("post", "http://localhost:3000/malesingle", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send(tojs);
```

My controller is something like this :

```
def new
    @tournoi = Tournoi.new

  end

  def create
      JSON.parse(params[:tournoi][:payload])
      @tournoi = Tournoi.new(bracket_params)
      if @tournoi.save
        redirect_to root_url
        #format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        flash[:success] = "Your tournament bracket has been validated!"
      #  redirect_to @tournoi
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end
  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the whitelist through.
    def bracket_params
      params.require(:tournoi).permit(:payload)
     end
```

I don't know if maybe because I'm using

```
<%= form_for Tournoi.new do |f| %>
  <button id="SaveButton" onclick="save()">Save</button>
<% end %>
```

to submit a new Tournoi, but `form_for (@tournoi)`, won't even render the view.
 Every time I tried to submit, the JSON content his showed on the terminal but I get a

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

followed by a

> NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)

and a

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):

I can't seem to find where I went wrong tried shifting things around my code I get back to the same point.

Comment: the error message displayed in your Rails server terminal should tell you which line is failing. Please find & then highlight this line in your question. But basically, it seems that you are calling the `[]` method on `nil`. This is probably because `params[:tournoi]` is `nil` in your context.

Comment: I'd recommend that you go through some basic tutorials to see how the form is written in rails and how form values are passed on to the controller/action.

Comment: @MrYoshiji apparently issue is in my controller in `app/controllers/tournois_controller.rb:8:in `create'
` . For the MethodError but what i dont get is the TypeError(no implicite conversion of nil into String) it seems like the my actions post is to be able to fill the nil with a String (my JSON).

Comment: Please highlight (by updating your answer pointing to) the line where the error occurred. We don't have the same line numbers in your answer as you have in your code-base.

Comment: In order to _inspect_ your params received in your `create` action, you can use `byebug` (breakpoints in Ruby) or do a simple `raise params.inspect` as the first instruction in your `create` action. It will actually raise an error with the message bering the content of `params`, which seems to not be the one you expect

Comment: Even inspecting params doesnt make me understanding whats going on, keep on getting error just a different one this type, this time its a `RuntimeError ()`.  it seems like just sending my request isnt fully submitting it into payload, is there a way i can introduce the variable throu my controller, someway of forcing the post into my model attribute.

Comment: @MrYoshiji sorry for the lack of understanding this is my first project alone learning as i go along,

Comment: i tried just to render params inspect into my html, with this line : `<%= params.inspect %>`, the following text shows at the bottom `<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"tournois", "action"=>"malesingle"} permitted: false>` @MrYoshiji

Comment: this is a guide on how to do this with jquery .. it should be easy, your controller is getting no parameters so maybe you are not sending or maybe your are just not receiving them
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237720/jquery-post-to-rails?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: im sending the payload my controller isnt receiving it